# "поделиться" от Яндекса data-url не работает

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

В `data-url` ссылка на конкретный объект, однако **"поделиться"** срабатывает на всю страницу... подскажите, где копнуть!
[ссылка](https://bfba.ru/koshki/vzroslyie/)

Comment: Не очень понятна проблема, опиши пожалуйста подробнее

Comment: Неправда, у вас там прописано ira.html — делится именно ira.html, всё в порядке

Comment: Да, адрес генерится, но ссыла при нажатии "поделиться" дает на всю страницу, а не на конкретного котика

Comment: еще раз ссыла - кто владеет вопросом - помогите) https://bfba.ru/koshki/vzroslyie/

Comment: @chilovik неправда, я проверял во ВК — при клике по ссылке в посте открывается именно ira.html, всё в полном порядке

Comment: @chilovik если вас запутало то, что в заголовке у ira.html написано «Взрослые», то меняйте `data-title` на нужный вам, а с `data-url` всё в порядке

Comment: спс! ковыряю)))

Comment: Вот спасибо! Не проверил открытие. С картинками разберусь уже. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Всеж таки что-то пошло не так.. Вот мой вывод:

Comment: <p>Рассказать друзьям:</p> <script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" 
data-url="[[+data-url]]"
data-title="[[+pagetitle]]"
data-image="[[+tv.news_image?]]"
data-size ="s" 
data-services="vkontakte,facebook,odnoklassniki,moimir,gplus,twitter,lj,telegram"></div>

Comment: В таком раскладе имя кота всегда одно и то же, ВК появляется пустое вообщение..Кто может, помогите!))